# cuda performance constraints: conditional branching

Tags: cuda

Guys I want to know something related cuda performance about conditional branching. I have the following code

```
if(i==5)
i=10;
else
i=5;
```

Now instead of this if i use the following statement will it remove the n/2 performance bottleneck in cuda?

```
i=(i==5)?10:5;
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the "n/2 performance bottleneck" you are referring to is warp divergence due to conditional branching.

It's likely that in either formulation you have shown, the compiler will make use of [predicates](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#predicated-execution) to avoid branching altogether, and probably both cases will compile to similar or identical machine code.

The compiler will make aggressive use of predicated execution in order to avoid branches and warp divergence.

In general, making valid inferences about machine behavior from C/C++ source code is quite difficult.  Instead, compare both cases by compiling to ptx (`nvcc -ptx ...`), or even better is to do an ordinary compile and dump the machine code using `cuobjdump -sass my_executable`.